# Why doesn't PhpStorm code completion work on such a simple block of code?

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, code-completion

I've noticed lately that code completion has been less effective in PhpStorm and I'm not sure if my settings are messed up or I'm just missing something.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Database {
    public function doStuff() {}
}

class DatabaseTest {
    private $conn;

    /**
     * DatabaseTest constructor.
     * @param $dbc
     */
    public function __construct($dbc) {
        $this->conn = $dbc;
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->conn->
    }
}
$dbc = new Database();
$databaseTest = new DatabaseTest($dbc);
```

The problem here is code completion in the test function will not work correctly

1. PhpStorm will not add types to the auto generated docblock for the constructor even though it should be able to deduce the type.
2. Even if the docblock isn't correct or the parameter isn't type hinted, shouldn't PhpStorm be able to determine the object type based upon the argument sent?

I realize that if I type hint the constructor parameter or the doc block I'll get the expected results but I feel like PhpStorm should have been able to figure this one out.

I'm using PhpStorm 2018.1.6

I'm sure I'm overlooking something and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you should include the class in the @param directive. like : `@param FeedServlet $servlet`, where FeedServlet is the class of parameter `$servlet`. Thus in you case `@param Database $dbc` (using a doc-comment solution).

Answer (score 1):

The reason PHPStorm doesn't autocomplete in this case is because, given your code and the absence of type-hinting/typed `@param` in the constructor, there could be several `Database` instances where `$this->conn` is of different types.

Let's pretend you add this at the end of your sample code:

```
$dummy = new \stdClass;
$databaseTest2 = new DatabaseTest($dummy);
```

Now what should PHPStorm autocomplete `$this->conn` (within the class) as? It could be either a `Database` instance or a `\stdClass`, or just anything else really.

Edit: Well, guess it technically *could* parse all constructor calls and consider it as a `Database|\stdClass|...|otherClasses`, but then it would then also have to check all `$this->conn` assignments as well (since it can be of any type)... Doubt it'd be worth it (not to mention the CPU time it'd take if there's a lot of code).